# mailcatcher wont start up

Tags: rubygems, oh-my-zsh, mailcatcher

I am following the http://mailcatcher.me/ documentation

1. gem install mailcatcher
2. mailcatcher
3. Go to http://localhost:1080/
4. Send mail through smtp://localhost:1025

I was able to install mailcatcher

```
Fetching: mailcatcher-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mailcatcher-0.6.1
Parsing documentation for mailcatcher-0.6.1
Installing ri documentation for mailcatcher-0.6.1
Done installing documentation for mailcatcher after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I want to start the service by running the command `mailcatcher`
I get

```
/Users/MoisesZaragoza/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000440
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0015 p:-17558973087826 s:0069 e:000068 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0067 e:000066 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0113 s:0063 e:000062 METHOD /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0012 p:0080 s:0053 e:000052 TOP    /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0051 e:000050 CFUNC  :require
c:0010 p:0113 s:0047 e:000046 METHOD /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0009 p:0039 s:0037 e:000036 TOP    /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mailcatcher-0.6.1/lib/mail_catcher.rb:6 [FINISH]
c:0008 p:---- s:0035 e:000034 CFUNC  :require
c:0007 p:0113 s:0031 e:000030 METHOD /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0006 p:0007 s:0021 e:000020 TOP    /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mailcatcher-0.6.1/bin/mailcatcher:3 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0019 e:000018 CFUNC  :load
c:0004 p:0135 s:0015 E:002238 EVAL   /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/mailcatcher:23 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0011 e:000010 CFUNC  :eval
c:0002 p:0118 s:0005 E:001350 EVAL   /Users/ShipSticks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:001928 TOP    [FINISH]
```

Comment: have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went wrong at `eventmachine` level. Try reinstalling eventmachine (or upgrade to a newer version).

If this still does not work, try using MailCatcher in a container (see [MailCatcher Docker using Alpine](https://github.com/spaquet/alpinemailcatcher)). Using containers for your projects can save you time as they remain more stable, especially when you have to upgrade your OS or move to a new PC.

Answer (score 0):

In my case windows 10 latest with subsystem linux ubuntu 16.04 command  `gem install mailcatcher` solved issue.